# The Plugin.MediaManager produces 'Unknown option' error

Tags: visual-studio-2022, media-manager

on starting a new xamarin forms project and just adding Plugin.MediaManager.Forms v1.1.1 then rebuilding it produces error:

**Unknown option `-RC:\Users\Hp..\flat\values-en-rIN_values-en-rIN.arsc.flat`. Please check `$(AndroidAapt2CompileExtraArgs)` and `$(AndroidAapt2LinkExtraArgs)` to see if they include any `aapt` command line arguments that are no longer valid for `aapt2` and ensure that all other arguments are valid for `aapt2`.**

The Line *CrossMediaManager.Current.Init();* has been added in constructor.
The error occurs only if i add MediaManager. Ive tried with MediaManager 0.9.7 till 1.1.1
No improvement

Earlier with VS2019 it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got it
enter the following in the Android csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette" Version="1.0.0.5" />
 
 ...
```

in the item group which contains xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials etc

Comment: Thanks, @Mansoor Malik for the effort !